# Isn't supposed to have higher win rate with meta audience than with applovin max?

Tags: facebook-audience-network, applovin

Recently I have realized that my app is making lower revenue, win and fill rate with meta audience network. I firmly believe that it is supposed to make higher revenue than with applovin max, how can I fix this?

I checked network, sdk everything ok

Comment: you must provide some additional information. In what sense your app is making more revenue on Applovin ? Is Applovin Giving Higher eCPM rates or something else? You need to provide some more information.  Have you given any Bid Floor in your Applovin Ad Unit Setup?

Comment: I have just created the unit ads